# jQuery .click() doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I'm having a secluded problem. I was creating a UI for something using jQuery when all of a sudden the .click() events stopped firing.

This jsFiddle has all of the related code:

http://jsfiddle.net/qgz2j/1/

If you look at the code, you can see that a `<div>` with id "target" contains two other `<div>`s, one with id "red" and one with id "green". Looking at the associated CSS, both have width 100% and are overlapped, but the green has `display:none;`.

As you can see, the `.click()` doesn't fire and no alert is shown. However, using this works:

```
<div id="target" onClick="alert('Clicked!')">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You chose a wrong framework. Change it From **Mootools** to **jQuery**.

[image]

Also It is a good practice to wrap your code inside the [**ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$(function(){     
       $('div#target').click(function() {
            alert('div has been clicked');
        });

});
​
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/qgz2j/4/

Comment: Wow. I feel really ignorant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

now check this you not append the jquery libary
http://jsfiddle.net/qgz2j/3/

Answer (score 2):

In the fiddle, Choose framework as jQuery and it should work. :P

http://jsfiddle.net/qgz2j/6/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine you just had your fiddle set to use MooTools instead of jQuery.  Take a look at this version:

http://jsfiddle.net/qgz2j/8/

All I did was tell it to use jQuery.